# ZFCuser keeping users

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

Is it possible to use accounts created by ZfcUser zf1 in zf2 project ?

Actually, I have a users list created by ZFCuser module (zf1) and i want use the same list with zf2 project.

If it's possible , How ?

Comment: Sure why would this not be possible? Are there any differences in the database model? What did you try so far to migrate your users?

Comment: @Wilt If you compare a hash generated by ZfcUser (zf1) and a hash generated by ZfcUser (zf2) are totally different(the content from password column)

Comment: The latest `ZfcUser` uses `BCrypt` for password encryption. What repository did you use for your ZF1 `ZfcUser` module? I cannot seem to find anything like that. Could you add a link to the both repositories to your question?